# override product attribute values on product detail page

Tags: product, attributes, product-attribute, category-products

Hei

We have tabs on product detail page and in specification tab I have length , weight attributes

Those have some decimal values, I want to override them, how can I achieve this??

Looking for solution

Comment: Please can u provide your code for get attribute value ???

Comment: As of know its default magento

Comment: which version of magento?

Comment: Version is Magneto 2.2.3